# How can I store a method's return statement in a variable? (python)

Tags: python, oop

I quite new to OOP (and python as well)
So I am building something similar to the Enigma machine.
My problem is that: 
I don't know how to access to the randomizer method's return statement.
I need that in order to get a randomized list of characters.

```
class generators():

    global static_alphabet,backup_alphabet,encripting_dict,decripting_dict, mutable_alphabet

    static_alphabet=['a','á', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','é', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i','í', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o','ó','ö','ő', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u','ú','ü','ű','v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',"'",'"','@',':','_','.','-',',','!']
    backup_alphabet=['a','á', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','é', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i','í', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o','ó','ö','ő', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u','ú','ü','ű', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',"'",'"','@',':','_','.','-',',','!']
    mutable_alphabet=[]

    def randomizer(self):

        mutable_alphabet=[]
        import random

        for element in static_alphabet:

            randletter=backup_alphabet[random.randint(0,len(backup_alphabet)-1)]

            while randletter==element:

                randletter=backup_alphabet[random.randint(0,len(backup_alphabet)-1)]
                if randletter!=element:
                    break

            mutable_alphabet.append(randletter)
            backup_alphabet.remove(randletter)
        return mutable_alphabet
```

Comment: Where are you calling `randomizer`?

Comment: `variable = gen.randomizer()` will store the return value in the variable.

Comment: That is not a class. That is a function with an unneeded argument and global data needlessly wrapped into an empty class. How are you using this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are trying to access the return statement inside a function (`def`) inside a `class`. While your code does not currently appear to be constructed to take advantage of OOP, here is how you would run that function within the same file:

```
class generators():
    ...your code...

gen = generators()
outputArray = gen.randomizer()

# confirm output by printing it out
print( outputArray )
```

This would need to be placed outside of the class as I tried to illustrate above.